# Turn FTP command into ASync Task?

Tags: android, ftp, android-asynctask

First off, don't flame me for not searching, I've looked for answers to this and while there are answers out there, I can't understand any of them.

Now, with that aside, I'm trying to put my ftp command into an ASync task for Android.

**Code**:

```
package com.dronnoc.ftp;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;
import org.apache.commons.net.io.CopyStreamEvent;
import org.apache.commons.net.io.CopyStreamListener;
import org.apache.commons.net.io.Util;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Main extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        FTPTransfer ftp = new FTPTransfer("hostname", "user", "pass");

        String data = Environment.getDataDirectory().toString();
        data += "/data/com.dronnoc.ftp/databases/test.db";

        boolean result = ftp.upload(data, "/ftp_dir/test.db");
        if(result)
        {
            Log.d("message", "Upload Successful.");
        }
        else
        {
            Log.e("message", ftp.error());
        }

    ftp.close();
    }
}
```

**FTPTransfer.java**

```
package com.dronnoc.ftp;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.SocketException;

import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPConnectionClosedException;


public class FTPTransfer {

    final FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();
    private String error = null;
    private boolean connected = false;

    public FTPTransfer(String host, String username, String pass) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        try {
            ftp.connect(host);

            if(ftp.login(username, pass))
            {
                ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();
                connected = true;
            }
        }
        catch (FTPConnectionClosedException e) { error = e.getMessage(); }
        catch (SocketException e) { error = e.getMessage(); }
        catch (IOException e) { error = e.getMessage(); }
    }


    public boolean upload(String localName, String remoteName)
    {
        if(ftp.isConnected() && connected)
        {
            try {
                FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(localName);
                boolean result = ftp.storeFile(remoteName, file);
                if(result) { return true; }
                else { return false; }
            } 
            catch (FileNotFoundException e) { error = e.getMessage(); return false; } 
            catch (IOException e) { error = e.getMessage(); return false; }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean upload(File localName, String remoteName)
    {
        if(ftp.isConnected() && connected)
        {
            try {
                FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(localName.getAbsolutePath());
                boolean result = ftp.storeFile(remoteName, file);
                if(result) { return true; }
                else { return false; }
            } 
            catch (FileNotFoundException e) { error = e.getMessage(); return false; } 
            catch (IOException e) { error = e.getMessage(); return false; }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean download(String remote, String local)
    {
        //TODO Put appropriate code here
        return false;
    }


    public boolean close()
    {
        try {
            ftp.disconnect();
            return true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            error = e.getMessage();
            return false;
        }
    }

    public String error()
    {
        return error;
    }

}
```

What I want to know is how I can put my FTP function into an ASync task so that I can run it in a background activity and update a progress bar, and also indicate how many bytes its uploaded so far?

Cheers

**EDIT**
The code itself works at the moment, I just need to know how to make it into an Async task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you're asking how to use the `AsyncTask` but in case you are here's a tutorial about using `AsyncTask` to make requests to a web service. This can be extended easily to perform FTP in the background. `AsyncTask` can also support Progress though I don't think it's mentioned in the tutorial.

Basically your `upload` function needs to move to `doInBackground` and so does the connection code. See http://geekjamboree.wordpress.com/2011/11/22/asynctask-call-web-services-in-android/

Comment: Thanks, that helped me understand it a little more, though I'm not entirely sure on how to impliment it? I've never had to work with an Async task before, so I haven't had any experience at all